# What is the average CO2 emission for a human while debating?

Tags: carbon-footprint, greenhouse-gas-emissions

I am looking to calculate the CO2 emission of an average male human while arguing/debating.

It is my understanding that the amount of CO2 emitted will be based on the respiratory rate of any given human over a period of time. According to [this seemingly well-researched post](https://www.globe.gov/explore-science/scientists-blog/archived-posts/sciblog/2008/08/11/release-of-carbon-dioxide-by-individual-humans/comment-page-1/index.html) an average adult human is estimated to produce between 700 and 900g of CO2 per day based on food intake (former estimate) and breaths per day at 16 breaths per minute (latter estimate).

This is a helpful start, but in my case I am interested in humans actively debating/conversing, would conversing result in more breaths per minute and added exertion and CO2 emission, or would it be negligible?

Is this even measurable?

Answer (score 3):

I think you've misunderstood the CO2 issue. The problem with greenhouse gases, the way in which they present a threat to the very existence of human civilisations, is because we are **adding** C/CO2 to the carbon cycle.

Growing food, eating food, metabolising food, exhaling CO2, is wholly **within** the carbon cycle: that is, it does not in itself **add** extra C/CO2 to the cycle. Some food production does add C/CO2 to the carbon cycle: fossil-fuel uses in the food supply chain, or greenhouse gas emissions from land-use changes or from livestock.

Furthermore, not only is CO2 exhaled by living creatures irrelevant to the greenhouse gas problem, but you also may have misunderstood human metabolism. Conversing uses negligible additional amounts of energy relative to standing there saying nothing, so the additional exhalation of CO2 is miniscule.

Comment: I'd argue that growing food is not completely within the carbon cycle, depending on the type of food you're talking about. Especially meat adds not only CO2 but also methane to the atmosphere, increasing the amount of CO2-equivalents.

Answer (score 0):

**It is measurable**,

if you put an arbitrary amount of people inside a room with a carbon dioxide sensor.

---

You would need to do two tests.

**Test one:**

- make them converse on a topic which interests everyone, but is neutral
- play a relaxing video in the background, probably one of a beach
- play soft noises
- use green light
- make the room as relaxing as possible

**Test two**:

- make them argue
- play an unrelaxing video in the background, probably a horror movie
- put on aggravating noise
- use red light
- make the room as unrelaxing as possible

---

**Safety aspects:**
The exact legal boundaries for such experiments are unknown to me, here are some precautions that should be taken, to increase the safety.

The individuals should:

- sign a form or document, so they agree on not using physical violence as an example
- be mentally stable and able to endure the experiment
- face a psychological examination before and after the experiment
- never be exposed to a dangerous amount of carbon dioxide

---

**Statistical requirements**

- The tests would also need to be done multiple times, so the result is more accurate and not bound as much to randomness
- A paired t-test would suit the experiment well
- You could also obtain additional values, like age, gender, or physical condition(older people could emit less carbon dioxide in an argument)
- If former is the case it is also important to think about data protection laws, the individuals can be asked if they allow the raw data to be published or you could use statistical methods to hide the original data from the public